# What is the difference between Broadcast Receiver and service?

Tags: android

I wrote program for broadcast receiver and service, but i confused in the manifest file there is some ground work to register service and receiver, will any one give me clear idea about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Service

- It is used when you want to do something in background, any long running process can be done using Service in Background.
- This will be running always in background even if the application closed
- For example, you want to play music when your application gets close. In that case service will be running in background with music.

### BroadcastReceiver

- It is used when you want to fire some stuff or code during some event. For example, event can be on Boot of Device.
- Usually system will send some info which can be recieved by your app if you would wish to ,by registering. And you can do something what you want when that thing happens by using onReceive method. Example is the system will send BroadcastReceiver when new sms arrives or Booting done
- for example, If you want to perform something when device Boots, date and time changed etc.

Answer (score 1):

A service is used to perform long running operations without user interaction or to supply functionality to other applications.

```
A Service needs to be declared in the AndroidManifest.xml via  
a <service android:name="yourclasss"> </service> and the implementing class  
must extend the Service class or one of its subclasses.  

To start Services automatically after the Android system starts you can register  
a BroadcastReceiver to the Android android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED system  
event. This requires the android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED permission.
```

For more details, check this http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html#pre_broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 0):

A broadcast receiver is an Android component which allows to register for system or application events. All registered receivers for an event will be notified by Android once this event happens.

A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.

It'll be very long to explain it all here
I've got 2 great tutorial links from vogella

[Broadcast Receiver](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

[Service](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html)

if you have further question after reading the tutorial feel free to ask me in the comment :)